# Avantfax sending html coverpage with pdf fax fails

Tags: ghostscript

I hope someone is familiar with the avantfax system. (posted this on their forum but I think the project might be dead)

If I send the coverpage only the fax goes throught everything is happy. 
If I send an attached PDF (no cover) it sends fine as well. 
If I attach an HTML coverpage to a PDF fax it fails with this:

```
status:Error: /syntaxerror in --%ztokenexec_continue--\ 
Operand stack:\ \ Execution stack:\ %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push >--nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1910 1 3 %oparray_pop 1909 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop 1787 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval--\ 
Dictionary stack:\ --dict:1165/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:81/200(L)-- --dict:67/120(L)--\ 
Current allocation mode is local\ 
Last OS error: No such file or directory\ 
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1\
```

If I choose a PS coverpage with a PDF attachment it goes but none of the fields in the PS coverpage are converted (XXXX-to is still XXXX-to)

As it says no such file or directory, i checked file permissions and I done see anythign really obvious (I even opened them up to 777 just for giggles in just about every logical folder I could think of)

AvantFax 3.3.3

Hylafax version: 3:6.0.6-5 (installed from apt-get)

Debian 7

t38modem: 2.0.0-3

Answer (score 0):

You can't send HTML to Ghostscript, it only consumes PostScript or PDF. Attempting to parse HTML as PostScript is never going to work.

I have no idea what you mean when you say 'none of the fields in the PS coverpage are converted'. PostScript doesn't **have** fields.

The last OS error is probabl;y coming through from the fax system, because Ghostscript won't have produced an output file for it to read. SO its a red herring. The actual error is given by '/syntaxerror in --....' and basically says 'this syntax doesn't make sense', which is pretty much what you'd expect from sending HTML to it.

It 'sounds like' you want a dynamic cover page for your document, the only way to get that is to generate the page as either PostScript or PDF at the time its required, and use it. Possibly this is what the Avantfax system is supposed to do, I haven't a clue about it.

But sending HTML to Ghostscript isn't going to work.